# $f(x^4)=f(x)$ and $f$ continuous at $0$ and $1$ implies constant function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^4) = f(x) \forall x\in\mathbb{ R}$. Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ and $1$. Prove that $f(x)$ is a constant function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Could anyone inspire me how to start off?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in (-1,1)$ we have $x \ ^ {4n} \to 0$ so $f(x \ ^{4n}) \to  f(0)$ , but, by induction you can show that $f(x \ ^{4n} ) = f(x  ^ 4) = f(x)$ so $f(x) = f(0)$.

For $x \in (1,\infty)$ take $x \ ^{1/4n} \to 1$  , by similar arguments you can show $f(x) = f(1)$.

For $x \in (-\infty , -1)$ we have $f(x \ ^ 4 ) = f((-x) \ ^ 4 )  = f(x) = f(-x)$ , so $f(x) = f(1)$ also , by the previous part.

Now you need to show $f(1) = f(0)$ and you are done.

Comment: Do not that I need to prove $f(x)$ is also constant in $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)$.

Comment: @user122049 you wanted inspiration of how to start off :P ,i edited my answer for other $x$s

Answer (score 0):

For any natural number n ,f(x)=f(4n th root of modulus of x)
. Now use the fact that f is continuos at 0 and 1 and if n goes to infinity n th root of any positive number goes to 1.continuity at 1 is needed to show f(x)=f(1)  if x is nonzero and continuity at zero is needed to show f(0)=f(1)